# Download Older version of Meteor

Tags: version, meteor

IS it possible to download older version of meteor.

A code tht I am using (I didn't write it) was stable for version 0.34. Its not working for 0.5.

Arindam

Answer (score 6):

This is not official, but by analyzing install.meteor.com I found it easy to download older versions of Meteor.

Here's an example of Meteor 0.3.4 for Mac: https://d3sqy0vbqsdhku.cloudfront.net/meteor-package-Darwin-x86_64-0.3.4.tar.gz

Linux: https://d3sqy0vbqsdhku.cloudfront.net/meteor-package-Linux-x86_64-0.3.4.tar.gz

But I would highly recommend rewriting your app to adopt the latest API. If that is not an option, here's the step-by-step instruction to install older meteor(not official!).

1. In your terminal type: `curl -L http://install.meteor.com > meteor.sh`
2. Open `meteor.sh` in a text editor and change the `VERSION`(*around line #8*) to the version required. Like so:

   ```
   URLBASE="https://d3sqy0vbqsdhku.cloudfront.net"
   VERSION="0.3.4"
   PKGVERSION="${VERSION}-1"
   ```
3. Install Meteor by typing the following in your terminal: `sh meteor.sh`

Hope this helps.

Comment: The URL has changed to https, so the correct is: `curl -L https://install.meteor.com > meteor.sh`

Comment: Works for me by `curl https://install.meteor.com > meteor.sh` without the -L option

Answer (score 2):

An easier way: Use [meteorite](http://oortcloud.github.com/meteorite/):

In your `smart.json`

```
"meteor": {
  "git": "https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git",
  "tag": "v0.3.4"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found for this is to just install the most recent version and run it with the `--release` flag.  This is suppose to run that version of meteor.

`> meteor --release 0.34`

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4526

Answer (score 1):

You can do like so:

```
curl "https://install.meteor.com/?release=1.3.3.1" | sh
```